# Is there a way to change the name that the NAO-robot uses in the Basic channel?

Tags: nao-robot

I want that my NAO-robot (Version 6) uses another name than NAO, when someone asks "What is your name?". I already changed it's name in the settings, but it doesnt use it by the voice recognition.

Comment: Which name does your robot utters when you push the torso button?

Answer (score 0):

The basic channel's content is probably generic and might not adapt to your robot's actual name. But by making a small app reacting on the same [trigger sentence](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/software/choregraphe/panels/project_content_panel.html#trigger-sentences), you might be able to override the current behavior.